# $y=\sin^2x+\sin x+1$. Find the range of $y$

Tags: trigonometry

The range of $\sin x$ is $[-1,1]$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you use calculus?

Comment: $4(u^2 + u + 1) = 4u^2 + 4u+4 = (2u+1)^2 + 3$ and you have $u= \sin x.$  What is the range of $u?$

Comment: Confusion implies you've tried the question, so which part did you get stuck on?

Comment: At what level is this? Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: A better way of asking questions is to attach your thoughts. Other people can see your efforts on questions.

Answer (score 3):

You may convert the problem into
\begin{equation}
y = x^{2} + x + 1, -1 \leq x \leq 1.
\end{equation}
This is the standard form of quadratic functions $y = ax^{2} + bx + c$. Since $a = 1 > 0$ in this case, the function is of a minimum value if the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. The minimum value of $y$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is achieved at $-b/2a = -0.5$, which is within the range of $\left[-1,1\right]$. Then $y\left(-0.5\right) = 0.75$ is the minimum value. The maximum of $y$ is achieved at either $x = -1$ or $x = 1$. We have $y\left(-1\right) = 1$ and $y\left(1\right) = 3$. The function $y$ is continuous, and we have
\begin{equation}
0.75 \leq y \leq 3.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\displaystyle y=\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)+1=\frac{1}{4}\bigg[4\sin^2(x)+4\sin(x)+4\bigg]$$

$$y=\frac{1}{4}\bigg[\bigg(2\sin(x)+1\bigg)^2+3\bigg]\geq \frac{3}{4}$$

Also $$-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1\Longrightarrow -2 \leq 2\sin(x)\leq 2$$

$$-1\leq 2\sin(x)+1\leq 3\Longrightarrow 0\leq \bigg(2\sin(x)+1\bigg)^2\leq 3$$

So we get $$y=\frac{1}{4}\bigg[\bigg(2\sin(x)+1\bigg)^2+3\bigg]\leq 3$$

So we get range as $$y\in\bigg[\frac{3}{4}\;,\; 3\bigg]$$

Answer (score 0):

If you use calculus, then it won't be much time consuming as you just need to differentiate and apply Maxima-minima rule.
But if you're not allowed to use calculus, then the best method I would suggest is the *COMPLETING SQUARE METHOD* .
See, you'll have to convert the trigonometric terms into a perfect square somehow.
Here, the equation may be converted to-

Sin²x+Sinx+1
= Sin²x+2(1/2)(sinx)+(1/2)²-(1/2)²+1
=(Sinx+1/2)²+(3/4)

Now we have only one parameter i.e (sinx+1/2)
So, for maximum, put the maximum value of (sinx+1/2) there, which is 3/2 (at X=π/2 radians)

So the maximum value of the expression is :

## (3/2)²+3/4=12/4

Similarly, for minimum value, put the minimum value of |sinx+1/2| , which is equal to zero.

Here I used the modulus as we will have to square the term when we will put it in y....... Thus, the negative value will also become positive, but we want the minimum value, so we will put the minimum absolute value there (if an even power is associated in the expression).
Thus the minimum value becomes:
(0)²+3/4=3/4
Thus the range of y is [3/4,3].

Now you see, this method won't help you always but I can assure that this works most of the time.
So it's your liberty to use the calculus method (which works always) or this method.

Comment: The closed brackets here are used to show that the boundary values are also included in the range :)